# How do I import Eclipse Dynamic Web Project into IntelliJ?

Tags: eclipse, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I am new to Spring MVC, learning from a course and used to IntelliJ IDEA. I don't know how to create a Dynamic Web Project in IntelliJ, so I used to create the project files in Eclipse and then open the files from IntelliJ. But now that I have opened an Eclipse project into IntelliJ, it looks nothing like how the project files should look like. I have the Ultimate version of IntelliJ. Any help would be appreciated.

Eclipse view:

[image]

IntelliJ view:

[image]

Comment: How does the *course* say to create the project?

Comment: Hello, @nitind. The course just instructs to create Dynamic Web Project on Eclipse IDE which I can do fine. My problem is that I can't work on the same project file from IntelliJ with which I feel comfortable.

Comment: Is it possible to share project example?